# Couldn't install QGIS again in Mac after install random Plug in

Tags: qgis

Previously I the QGIS in my Mac could work, but after I install a plugin about hydrodynamic model it crashed the systems and now I couldn't re-install again the QGIS. Always appear this kind of information.

[image]
Could you help me to fix it so I can use QGIS again in my macbook. Thank you